# find the probability that more than 50 of the observations of the random sample are less than 3

Tags: probability

Let X1,X2,...,Xn be a random sample of size n=72 from a distribution with pdf

f(x)={1/x2    1<x<infinity
0      otherwise

Find the probability that more than 50 of the observations of the random sample are <3 (less than 3).

Comment: This is the third time (at least) that you have posted this routine homework problem.  Please pout some effort into it.  Voting to close.

Answer (score 0):

First calculate the probability that a single rv is less than 3, i.e.

$$\mathbb{P}[X_1<3]=p$$

Then use CLT to find the requested probability to get at least 51 successes on 72 independent trials